# PCINT0, PCINT1, PCINT2, etc. on ATtiny45/85

Tags: interrupt, attiny

According to the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf):

[image]

we could think that, if we want to have a pin change interrupt for 3 pins, we have to create multiple instances:

```
ISR(PCINT0_vect){
   ...
}

ISR(PCINT1_vect){
   ...
}

ISR(PCINT2_vect){
   ...
}

void setup(){
  GIMSK = 0b00100000;
  PCMSK = 0b00000111; 
}
```

However, this does not work, and I read [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70292/how-to-assign-an-interrupt-to-a-button-press-with-an-attiny-interrupt-not-fire/70330#70330) and [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=469577.msg3215283#msg3215283) that we have to define **just one** interrupt function:

```
ISR(PCINT0_vect){
   if (digitalRead(0) == LOW) 
     ...
   if (digitalRead(1) == LOW) 
     ...
   if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) 
     ...
}
```

Why is that so? What is `PCINT1, 2, 3`, ... made for then in this pinout schematics, if we don't have to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing Pin Change Interrupt *pins* with Pin Change Interrupt *vectors*. The two are very different.

Many Pin Change Interrupt *pins* are associated with just one Pin Change Interrupt *vector*.

You use the *pin* number (the value shown in the pinout) to decide if you want that pin to respond or not. You use the *vector* to respond any of the pins that are assigned to that vector.

In the ATTiny chips, since there are so few Pin Change Interrupt *pins* (8 or less) you only need one Pin Change Interrupt *vector* to handle them.

You can know if "PCINT4" corresponds to a *pin* or a *vector* by the context. If you see it on a pin then it is a pin. If you see it in code with `_vect` after it then it's a vector.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That is simply the difference between an external interrupt INTx and a pin change interrupt PCINT. The first is an interrupt for a single pin. The second is an interrupt for a complete group of pins. Normally this group is a complete port. As the Attiny85 only has one port, this is the case here. So the whole group is only 1 single interrupt source. Thus it only has one interrupt vector named `PCINT0_vect`.

A pin change interrupt triggers, when any of the pins under it's supervision changes. You can remove pins from it's supervision by masking them with the `PCMSK` register.

So the interrupt vector `PCINT_vect` will be triggered by every change on any of the pins, that are not masked out. It is up to you to check, which one changed it's level.

---

On bigger microcontrollers, there are more pins and mostly also most of them are connected to a pin change interrupt. Here mostly every complete port is connected to a single pin change interrupt. Thus the corresponding registers are additionally marked with a number (`PCINT0_vect` as the interrupt vector for the first port, ...)

Comment: Ok, so in fact for ATtiny45, `PCINT0_vect` works for all the pins 0..5? Then why put "PCINT1", "PCINT2" on the pinout schematics? Then `PCINT0_vect` should be called `PCINT_vect0`, don't you think so? Because it's the the "first" vector of pin change interrupts... With a naming like `PCINTx_vect`, we could think it's relative to the pin x since the pinout schematics shows `PCINTx` for every pin x=0..5.

Comment: I cannot say, why they named them as such, that is only known by Atmel. A `PCINT_vect0` doesn't exist, because their naming convention is `<Interrupt Name>_vect` for the interrupt vectors. For the pin description I think, they wanted to keep it short. On bigger microcontrollers, the PCINT pins are numbered completely though, so on the Atmega328P (from the Uno) there are pins up to PCINT20

Comment: Basically you need to understand what Pin Change interrupts are. Those things are normally explained rather detailed in the datasheet. For example this sentence from the External Interrupt section of the datasheet: "Pin change interrupts PCI will trigger if any enabled PCINT[5:0] pin toggles."

Comment: I know what they are, and I do understand they are grouped, but I don't understand the naming...

Comment: For example for the 328p, `PCINT0_vect` covers which group of pins? Idem for `PCINT1_vect`? I can imagine they can handle up to 8 pins each?

Comment: If you look at the register description for the corresponding mask registers in the datasheet, you see that each bit of the mask is marked with the corresponding pin name. Also in the description of the PCI enable bits you find the information, for which pins they are used and also which mask register.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101275/discussion-between-chrisl-and-basj).

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable Pin Change INTerrupts for individual pins using the Pin Change Mask Register `PCMSK`.

The names on the pins map the bit in `PCMSK` to the physical pin.

You find more information in section 9.3.4 on p. 52 in the [ATtiny85 Data Sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: I did this with `PCMSK = 0b00000111;` indeed. But why don't we use `PCINT1_vect`? The pinout schematics mentions "PCINT1", why don't we use it?

Comment: Section 9.1 lists all available interrupt vectors. Pin Change Interrupts are grouped to not waste resources. Only `INTx` is dedicated to a single pin. It is also much more powerful, als it can be triggered on rising or falling edges instead of each change. ATtiny85 only has with INT0 one dedicated pin for that.

Comment: I understand that they are grouped to not waste resources @Kwasmich, but then if all pins can be handled with just `PCINT0_vect` alone, isn't this a mistake in the schematics to write PCINT0, PCINT1, ..., PCINT5?

Comment: No, again, it is to show you wich bit in `PCMSK` corresponds to which physical pin. Otherwise you would not know what pin is affected. The naming is ambiguos, for sure.